# Signing an ActiveX DLL to use in Internet Explorer with VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, dll, com, activex, certificate

I've programmed a simple ActiveX COM with VC++ 6 that returns some data and I need this control to run into a HTML page in Internet Explorer 6 on my company network without asking for certificates and without need to change ActiveX security configuration on the browser.

The steps I've done:

1. DLL COM created on VC6 and registered (regsrv32) and tried from VB6 and it works.
2. I tried to run it locally through an html/vbscript page using **CreateObject("testcom.myclass")** and it works (after accepting all the untrusted execution warnings and so on from IE).
3. I created selfsigned Root CA and intermediate certificates as described here: http://www.top20toolbar.com/misc/codesigncert.htm and I install those certificates on IE as explained also there (On a test computer from the network).
4. I signed the DLL (also from the previous website) and installed on the test computer.

With all that, I get my script as untrusted and as I've disable the IE option:
**"Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe"** it just doesn't run and give me the **error 429: ActiveX Component cannot create the object**.
If I change the option to enable or prompt it works.

Could you help me somehow in what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mark the activeX object as "safe for scripting" and "safe for initialization" ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Saibal, I didn't mark as you said. I'm reading the website and trying the code but it gives me error while using: StringCchLength and StringCchCopy. Those functions are undefined as I'm using VC++6 and I don't have strsafe.h :\ Any idea where I can get it? I've platform SDK installed aswell

Comment: Try using strcpy or a similar function instead.

Comment: Hi Saibal, I managed to get it working with StringCch* under Windows 2003. 
The point is that my project is a ATL project instead of just an ActiveX Control project, so there're some GUID variables used in the code described on the link that I don't have.
As I just need a simple attribute get from my component, I thought it's just enough and ATL COM DLL, but should I create an ActiveX Control for this??

Comment: Finally I used normal ActiveX Control and using the link u posted to sign and it works perfect.
Thank you very much